# hline and ifthen and xtab

Tags: tables

I'm trying to debug the layout of a bunch of program-generated tables (some using `longtable` for historical reasons, some using `tabular`, some using `xtab`). I'd really like to use `\hline` after each line of these tables to see what's going on, and then suppress the `\hline` when I no longer need it for debugging. (I'd like to do the same thing with the vertical lines produced by `|' in the table-description, but that seems even less likely.)

I used `ifthen` to define `\hhline`, which is `\hline` if some flag is set, and nothing otherwise, but this failed because of some peculiarity described in other questions here. For the record, I wrote:

```
\newcommand{\lineflag}{true}
\newcommand{\hhline}{\ifthenelse{\equal{\lineflag}{true}}{\hline}{}}%
```

and then in my table, I had things like

```
\begin{xtabular}{|p{\indexPageWidth}|p{\indexNameWidth}|}\hhline
}
```

at the start to draw a line at the top of the table, and LaTeX objected, of course.

As I say, I understand from reading other q-and-a that this won't work as I've done it. Is there some way to get the same result, i.e., to say "show me the outline shapes of all table cells when some flag is true, and not otherwise"?

A minimal(ish) broken example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{xtab}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\begin{document}

\begin{xtabular}
{p{1.0in}|p{2.0in}}
first item & second item\\
third item & fourth item
\end{xtabular}

\vspace{0.3in}
Now with hlines:

\begin{xtabular}
{p{1.0in}|p{2.0in}}
first item & second item\\\hline
third item & fourth item \\\hline
\end{xtabular}

\newcommand{\lineflag}{false}
\newcommand{\oline}{\ifthenelse{\equal{\lineflag}{true}}{\hline}{}}%
\vspace{0.3in}
Now with optional hlines; notice that the middle divider hangs down     because 
of the macro (even though it expands to nothing at all).
I also wish I could get an hline at the top as well, but I haven't figured that out either. 
Changing ``lineflag'' to ``true'' above will generate an error. 

\begin{xtabular}
{p{1.0in}|p{2.0in}}
first item & second item\\\oline%
third item & fourth item \\\oline%
\end{xtabular}

\end{document}
```

Following @DavidCarlisle's advice, I modified the last third of that file to

```
\newif\iflineflag
\lineflagtrue
% \lineflagfalse

\iflineflag\hline\fi

\begin{xtabular}
{p{1.0in}|p{2.0in}}
first item & second item\\\iflineflag\hline\fi
%
third item & fourth item \\\iflineflag\hline\fi
%
```

...and once I got rid of some silly cruft, it worked perfectly. I'd rather be able to put a single command line `\oline` rather than `\iflineflag\hline\fi`, but I can work with this.

Comment: What is the `xtabular` environment?? Do you mean `tabularx` or `xltabular` (an extension of tabularx which can break across pages)?

Comment: @Bernard: Probably OP refers to the `xtabular` environment from the `xtab` package.

Comment: you don't give many clues but probably `\newif\iflineflag`   .. `\lineflagtrue` (or `\lineflagfalse`)  then ... `\iflineflag\hline\fi`

Comment: never heard of `xtabular` but if you meant `xtabular` or `xltabular` then there should be an X column.

Comment: Apologies -- I meant "xtab", but because it's the first time I've used it, I managed to forget that the environment name and the package name are different. And then I put my head down and started debugging and only just came back up.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I also tried your suggestion, and got the same `Misplaced \noalign` error.

Comment: @John then you did something wrong. Ah You added a test file, I'll add something

Comment: It's very likely that I did something wrong, alas. (...and it turns out I did, and that your solution works. My apologies for not getting it right from the clues you gave me.) And now from your answer I see that I CAN get that -- wonderful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an expandable test as you can have no non-expandable tokens before `\hline`

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{xtab}
\newif\iflineflag
\newcommand{\oline}{\iflineflag\hline\fi}%
\begin{document}

\begin{xtabular}
{p{1.0in}|p{2.0in}}
first item & second item\\
third item & fourth item
\end{xtabular}

\vspace{0.3in}
Now with hlines:

\begin{xtabular}
{p{1.0in}|p{2.0in}}
first item & second item\\\hline
third item & fourth item \\\hline
\end{xtabular}



\vspace{0.3in}
Now with optional hlines; notice that the middle divider hangs down     because 
of the macro (even though it expands to nothing at all).
I also wish I could get an hline at the top as well, but I haven't figured that out either. 
Changing ``lineflag'' to ``true'' above will generate an error. 


\bigskip
TRUE

\lineflagtrue
\begin{xtabular}
{p{1.0in}|p{2.0in}}
first item & second item\\\oline%
third item & fourth item \\\oline%
\end{xtabular}


\bigskip
FALSE

\lineflagfalse
\begin{xtabular}
{p{1.0in}|p{2.0in}}
first item & second item\\\oline%
third item & fourth item \\\oline%
\end{xtabular}

\end{document}
```